# Novell sles replica problem

Tags: replication, novell, sles10

We have a sles10 sp2 oes2 sp1 server that is in eDirectory as a replica server.  However in our ds ring it is not showing up. It shows up as synched for time but it will not show up in our replica ring.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to try:

Check for its local replicas/partitions by doing "ndsrepair -P". What partitions are displayed? The server may be in the tree but have no replicas (partitions) on it, which dovetails with geoffc's answer above, and is perfectly normal if the server was simply added to the tree.

If there is no replica but you want to add one, I would use iManager.

Also, while not directly related, I would definitely check the server's DNS entries using "host" and slp configuration using "slptool". These should make sure that it is communicating with the other servers in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a ndsrepair -T what is the replica depth value?  I forget the exact numbers, but -1 means no replicas locally.  Positive numbers are a reference to how far away from [Root] as I recall.

How did you add the replica to this server?  (If it is the second or third server into a partition then it will automatically get a replica of the partition it is inserted into.  This is in order to get to three copies of each replica for redundancy where possible)